# Send a PDF document as an attachment via email in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email-attachments

I am working on a web app in Laravel. I have programmed such that when a user enters data in a form, the **data is send to my email address**, the **user then gets a feedback message**. I want to attach a PDF document to the feedback message. Seeking assistance on **how to parse the user details from the controller to the PDF so that I can use it then attach to the feedback message**..

~ Regards

**Controller**

```
public function postContact(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'message' => 'required|min:20',
                'checkbox' => 'required']);

        $data = array(
                'name' => $request->name,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
                'email' => $request ->email,
                'checkbox' => $request ->checkbox,
                'bodyMessage' => $request->message
            );

         //code to send email to my inbox
        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('info@************');
        });

        //Feedback mail to client
        Mail::send('emails.feedback', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from('info@**********');
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Thank you message');
            //Attach PDF doc
            $message->attachData($data, 'pdf.customer']);
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Hello &nbsp;'.$data['name'].'&nbsp;Thank You for choosing us. Will reply to your query as soon as possible');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Comment: You can edit pdf and can add user details on first page before sending it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use this package for creating a pdf file which can be attached later for sending it to mail.
[Laravel-PDF generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

after settingup the above package use the below sample code for generating pdf

public function postContact(Request $request){

```
    $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|min:20',
            'checkbox' => 'required']);

    $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'email' => $request ->email,
            'checkbox' => $request ->checkbox,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

     //code to send email to my inbox
    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('info@************');
    });

    //Feedback mail to client
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('your_view_name', $data)->setPaper('a4'); 
    Mail::send('emails.feedback', $data, function($message) use ($data,$pdf){
            $message->from('info@**********');
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Thank you message');
            //Attach PDF doc
            $message->attachData($pdf->output(),'customer.pdf');
        });

    Session::flash('success', 'Hello &nbsp;'.$data['name'].'&nbsp;Thank You for choosing us. Will reply to your query as soon as possible');

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help sir,, Would you mind explaining to me what setPaper method in `$pdf = PDF::loadView('your_view_name', $data)->setPaper('a4'); `  does ?

Comment: @Pweb setPaper() is optional and it accepts 2 parameters i.e 1st is paper size 2nd is orientation of page.  **e.g setPaper('a4', 'landscape')**

Comment: @Pweb I hope your problem is resolved using this package.Its my pleasure to help you.

Comment: @Pweb if my answer helped you please mark it as helpful but voting up so that other's can reach to this issue quickly.

Comment: ,,, I am still having some problems loading the view. It displays the mesage of **PDF document might not be displayed correctly** on the browser.. Would you mind showing me how to set the the application type?